# Repeat iteration in a for loop in r

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a for loop that will repeat a sequence of the following:

```
sample(x  = 1:14, size = 10, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4)
```

I want it to repeat 5000 times. So far, I include the above as the body of the loop and added

```
for (i in seq_along[1:5000]){
```

at the beginning but I am getting an error message saying

```
Error in seq_along[1:10000] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable
```

Comment: Try `for (i in 1:5000)`. `seq_along` is a function, `[ ]` is used for subsetting. So basically with `seq_along[1:5000]` you tried to subset a function, which caused your error. Btw. you are missing a closing `)` in your `sample()`-function.

Comment: Possible you intended `x = 1:4`?  That would align with your 4 `prob` values.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues here.

- @MartinGal noted the syntax issues with `seq_along` and the missing `)`.  Note that you can use `seq(n)` or `1:n` in defining the number of loops.
- You are not storing the sampled vectors anywhere, so the for loop will run the code but you won't capture the output.
- You have `x = 1:14` but you only have 4 `prob` values, which suggests you intended `x = 1:4` (either that or you are 10 `prob` values short).

Here's one way to address these issues using a for loop.

```r
n <- 5
s <- 10
xmax <- 4
p <- 1/4
out <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = s, byrow = TRUE)

set.seed(1L)
for (i in seq(n)) {
  out[i, ] <- sample(x = seq(xmax), size = s, replace = TRUE, prob = rep(p, xmax))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We need `replicate`

```
out <- replicate(5000, sample(x  = 1:14, size = 10, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4)), simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: While I like the simplicity of this solution, this code actually doesn't run, since the `sample`-function is broken. Either `x` or the probs need to be changed and the closing `)` is missing. I vote for removing the `prob` argument.

Answer (score 1):

As andrew reece notes in his comment, it looks like you want x = 1:4  Depending what you want to do with your result you could generate all of the realizations at one time since you are sampling with replacement and then store the result in a matrix with 5000 rows of 10 realizations per row. So:

```
x <- sample(1:4, size = 5000 * 10, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4))
result <- matrix(x, nrow = 5000)
```